# GIT error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git

Preciso de ajuda. Eu nao sei muita coisa sobre git e comecei a mexer agora. De alguma forma eu criei uma nova branch e agora nao consigo mais voltar para a branch master. Aparece o erro error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git. E o pior eh que eu criei essa branch sem querer. Nao me serve de nada. E eu nao consigo nem deleta-la. Eu to bem perdida. Se alguem tiver um material sobre git para me indicar tbm, eu agradeco.[image: Tela do git]

Answer (score 0):

Experimente deletar a pasta manualmente, em seguida abra o terminal no lugar onde ela costumava ficar e execute:

```
 git clone link
```

no lugar do "link" coloque o link da nuvem para seu repositório. Caso use o GitHub basta ir até o repositório, copiar o link do navegador e colar no terminal, dessa forma ele vai copiar a última versão upada e então você pode refazer as atualizações de código que quiser. Para evitar problemas, antes de fazer um push adquira o hábito de dar um git pull para baixar as atualizações que foram upadas por outrem e não gerar conflitos de versão

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso vc pode fazer um `git fetch` e vê o que é retornado do ambiente remoto e depois dar um `git branch` pra listar as branchs que existem no seu local.

Comment: Oii. Obrigada. Cara, eu usei git fetch e nao me retornou nada. E quando usei i git branch tbm nao retornou nada.

Comment: Então significa que não existe a branch que vc quer. Só existe localmente, então vc pode mandar ela pro remote.

`git push origin bug-456`

Answer (score 0):

você pode utilizar  git branch pra listar depois *git checkout* {NOME_BRANCH}, volte o último commit mas mantenha as informações git reset HEAD~1.

Para sua comodidade recomendo utilizar a versão gráfica do git disponivel em:

> [https://desktop.github.com/][1]

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Oii. Obrigada. Quando eu uso git branch, nao lista nenhuma branch pra mim. E no github desktop aparece so a branch master. E essa branch "bug-456" eh como se nao existisse.

Comment: você poderia fazer um teste clonar novamente o repositório, e ver se esta branch esta vindo do master.

Answer (score -1):

Talvez isso possa corrigir:

**git remote update

git fetch 

git checkout --track origin/"BRANCH-NAME"**

E também, é necessário verificar se a branch foi criada para o repositório correto. Caso tente fazer checkout na pasta/repositório errado dará este erro.